# Object reference error thrown while selecting the WebServiceDataSource for creating a table in Telerik Report Designer

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am new to Telerk Report Designer.

I have created a WebServiceDataSourcewith the name 'webServiceDataSource1', using an api and authorization token in the header. While creating the data source, it displayed the data preview correctly. But when I tried to create a table with that data source, an object reference error is thrown.

I created another WebServiceDataSource with the name 'DemoWebServiceDataSource' without any authorization token for testing purpose. It worked without any issues. But my requirement is to add the service using authorization token.

Screenshots attached.
[image: api added screen]
[image: authorization header added screen]
[image: preview of the url - success]
[image: error on selecting the service data source]
[image: api service without header-success]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the same value (Bearer key) on the "Configure request parameters" screen in the **Value** and **Design-Time Value** fields, currently your **Design-Time Value** is empty and most probably this causes the issue.
Alternatively, [in this blog post](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/webservice-data-source-component-telerik-reporting-report-server) the API key is send as a request parameter with **Name** apiKey, **Type** Query and **Value** and **Design-Time Value** both equal to your API Key (Header Authorization is not used).

[Here](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/how-to-connect-to-google-books-apis) is one more example for a Google API with key parameter.